# Postgres Group by intersection array

Tags: postgresql

I have a table like this

```
SELECT id, items
  FROM ( VALUES
    ( '1', ARRAY['A', 'B'] ),
    ( '2', ARRAY['A', 'B', 'C'] ),
    ( '3', ARRAY['E', 'F'] ),
    ( '4', ARRAY['G'] )
  ) AS t(id, items)
```

Two items belongs to the same group if the have at least one item in common.

For example #1 and #2 belongs to the same group because they both have A and B. #3 and #4 are other different group.

So my desidered output would be

| ID | items | group_alias |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | {A,B} | {A,B} |
| 2 | {A,B,C} | {A,B} |
| 3 | {E,F} | {E,F} |
| 4 | {G} | {G} |

The group_alias field is a new field that say to me that the record #1 and #2 belongs to the same group.

Comment: What would you do with `{B,C}` or `{C}`?

Comment: If #5 has `{B,C}`, what would `group_alias` look like?

Comment: @xehpuk It's fine to be a string or another array_agg(). The application will used it to group using string comparison.

Comment: @richyen it would be {B} and the same for #1 and #2. The minimum common item.

Comment: I don't understand your answer. If you have `{A,B}`, `{B,C}` and `{C,A}`, there is no "minimum common item".

Comment: In that case all should be together. I misspoke, if item #1 intersect with #2 but not with #3, they are grouped only if #2 intersect with #3.
Anyway, this is a rare case in my data. At least one letter is always present. It should be fine if we group byat least one intersection letter.

Comment: The problem is ill-defined. xehpuk's considerations remain unresolved.

Comment: Why is it ill-defined? What information is missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having

```
CREATE TABLE temp1
(
    id int PRIMARY KEY,
    items char[] NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO temp1 VALUES
( '1', ARRAY['A', 'B'] ),
    ( '2', ARRAY['A', 'B', 'C'] ),
    ( '3', ARRAY['E', 'F'] ),
    ( '4', ARRAY['G'] );

--Indexing array field to speedup queries   
CREATE INDEX idx_items on temp1 USING GIN ("items");
```

Then

```
select t1.*,
coalesce( (select t2.items  from temp1 t2 
            where t2.items && t1.items 
             and t1.id != t2.id 
             and array_length(t2.items,1)<array_length(t1.items,1) 
             order by array_length(t2.items,1) limit 1 )/*minimum common*/
            , t1.items /*trivial solution*/ )  group_alias
from temp1 t1;
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/46ydeE5ZXCJDk4Rw3cu4jt/10

Comment: The #2 should be with group_alias ["B"] because #1,#2 and 3# all contains at least "B".

Comment: I'll give it a try later. Is it a programming challenge?

Comment: No, it's a real case scenario for an application.

Comment: Now it works correctly, there was an error in ordering clause.

Comment: It works but when trying with larger dataset (100k rows) the query timeouts. Is there an alternative method?

Comment: Have you tried indexing items column as I added to answer?

Comment: In reality, the items array is created dynamically using array_agg()

Comment: Indexes in databases are dynamic, this kind of index (GIN) is for array operations.

Answer (score 0):

This query returns *all* group alias of an item. For example item no. 5 has group alias `{E}` and `{A,B}`. The performance is maybe better if you create a temporary table for the items instead of creating them dynamically like you mentioned in one comment. Temporary tables are automatically dropped at the end of a session. You can create
indexes on temporary tables, too, which can speed up the query.

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE temp
(
    id int PRIMARY KEY,
    items char[] NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO temp VALUES
( '1', ARRAY['A', 'B'] ),
( '2', ARRAY['A', 'B', 'C'] ),
( '3', ARRAY['E', 'F'] ),
( '4', ARRAY['G'] ),
( '5', ARRAY['A', 'B', 'E'] );
```

The query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    t1.id, t1.items, coalesce(match, t1.items) AS group_alias
FROM temp t1 LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        t2.id, match
    FROM
        temp t2,
        LATERAL(
            SELECT
                match
            FROM
                temp t3,
                LATERAL(
                    SELECT 
                        array_agg(aa) AS match
                    FROM 
                        unnest(t2.items) aa 
                    JOIN 
                        unnest(t3.items) ab 
                    ON  aa = ab
                ) AS m1
            WHERE 
                t2.id != t3.id AND t2.items && t3.items 
        ) AS m2
    ) AS groups 
ON groups.id = t1.id 
ORDER BY t1.id;
```

And the result:

```
 id |  items  | group_alias
----+---------+-------------
  1 | {A,B}   | {A,B}
  2 | {A,B,C} | {A,B}
  3 | {E,F}   | {E}
  4 | {G}     | {G}
  5 | {A,B,E} | {A,B}
  5 | {A,B,E} | {E}
```